# É seguro manter o contexto de um aplicativo em uma Singleton?

Tags: java, android

Eu tenho o costume de manter o contexto de um aplicativo Android salvo dentro de uma Singleton da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Global {
    private static Global instance;
    private Context context;

    public Global() {
    }

    public static Global getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Global();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, sempre que eu preciso usar algo que necessite de um contexto (por exemplo, um código dentro de um fragment), eu o faço da seguinte maneira:

```
Global.getInstance().getContext();
```

Minha pergunta é: isso é seguro do ponto de vista de um aplicativo? Pergunto isso pois normalmente defino o contexto como sendo a primeira Activity usada no aplicativo e não mudo o contexto no decorrer da aplicação. Isso pode gerar algum erro? Essa prática é aceitável/recomendável ou eu deveria obter o contexto toda vez que precisasse usá-lo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não e uma boa ideia ter sequer uma variável do contexto singleton porque existem vários tipos de context e cada um deles permite algo que uma outro possa não permitir. Uma das melhores formas de pelo menos melhorar sempre que for a utilizar o context e que sempre que for pegar ele de algum lugar faça :

```
context.getApplicationContext();
```

pois o applicationContext já e uma singleton.
Veja este artigo sobre os diferentes tipos de Context para os diferentes componentes(Activity, Service, BroadCastReceiver) e quando utilizar cada um deles.

http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: Concordo com o dario. E acrescento que nunca é bom manter uma instância de `Context` porque é um objeto pesado, ainda mais se for uma `Activity`. Muitas vezes as chamadas aos métodos dependem do ciclo de vida, que é diferente para cada um.

Comment: Obrigado Wakim! se voce for ver o link que esta no fim da resposta..existe uma tabel que demonstra as capacidades de cada tipo de context

Comment: Obrigado, não sabia muito a respeito do context, agora já tenho uma ideia melhor de como trabalhar com ele.

Answer (score 1):

Sua classe está mais ou menos. Mas o primeiro grande problema que eu vejo é o construtor ser público. Com isso, basta alguém invocá-lo e o seu singleton não mais será um singleton.

Há outro grande problema também: Sincronização. Basta duas `Threads` invocarem o `getInstance()` ou o `setContext(Context)` ao mesmo tempo e com um pouco de azar você pode acabar com duas instâncias do singleton, ou então com dois contextos distintos.

Além disso, há uma questão importante: Porque instanciar a classe `Global` de forma *lazy*? Ela não tem nenhum recurso pesado a ser instanciado no construtor. Com isso a sua classe fica assim:

```
public class Global {
    private static final Global instance = new Global();
    private Context context;

    private Global() {
    }

    public static Global getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public synchronized Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public synchronized void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

E assim já está legal, principalmente se você pretender adicionar mais coisas no seu singleton.

Algo que me preocupa um pouco é esse `setContext()`. O ideal é que o seu singleton seja imutável, e uma vez devidamente configurado, nunca mais seria mexido. Mas antes disso, vem a pergunta: Como você faz para obter o `Context`? Há vários contextos no android, qual contexto exatamente você está armazenando no seu singleton e porque você precisa fazer isso?

Além disso, **dependendo do caso** (não é em todo e qualquer singleton), você pode deixar os seus métodos estáticos, eliminando a necessidade de ter o `getInstance()`:

```
public class Global {
    private static final Global instance = new Global();
    private Context context;

    private Global() {
    }

    public static synchronized Context getContext() {
        return instance.context;
    }

    public static synchronized void setContext(Context context) {
        instance.context = context;
    }
}
```

E então você usaria apenas `Global.getContext();` ao invés de `Global.getInstance().getContext();`. Além disso, você nunca veria uma instância de `Global` fora da própria classe `Global` (o que é ótimo, uma vez que isso provavelmente não faria sentido).

Voltando na questão de multithreading, para evitar de ter os métodos `synchronized` você pode fazer a variável de instância `context` ser `volatile`:

```
public class Global {
    private static final Global instance = new Global();
    private volatile Context context;

    private Global() {
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance.context;
    }

    public static void setContext(Context context) {
        instance.context = context;
    }
}
```

Uma outra possibilidade é usar `AtomicReference<Context>` como o campo da classe:

```
public class Global {
    private static final Global instance = new Global();
    private final AtomicReference<Context> contextRef = new AtomicReference<>();

    private Global() {
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance.contextRef.get();
    }

    public static void setContext(Context context) {
        instance.contextRef.set(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: No seu exemplo, seria melhor o uso de "double-checked-locking".

Comment: @wyrel Discordo, ou ficaria errado ou ficaria desnecessariamente complexo para dar certo: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: Normalmente o Context é uma Activity. Mas me pareceu bastante errado fazer isso, daí veio a pergunta. Poderia me dizer qual é o significado desse synchronized? Nunca vi ele em nenhum outro lugar.

Comment: @RenanLazarotto http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html e também http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html

Comment: @Victor, obrigado! Uma leitura muito interessante, sequer conhecia isso!

Comment: @Victor, no link que você postou, olhe o trecho do "Fixing Double-Checked Locking using Volatile". Eu pessoalmente prefiro o double check locking à synchronizar um método inteiro.

Comment: @wyrel Sim, mas neste caso você está trocando o `synchronized` pelo `volatile`. No caso de um getter e setter simples até que não tem problema e o `volatile` é de fato um pouco melhor, mas se o campo que você estiver manipulando for algo mais complicado a coisa muda de figura. Entretanto eu tenho uma solução ainda melhor: usar `AtomicReference`.

Answer (score 1):

Como já foi dito, o contexto da `Activity` não deve ser mantido além do ciclo de vida da própria `Activity`. O contexto ideal para ser guardado é o contexto global do aplicativo.

Tenho uma sugestão para você obter o contexto global a qualquer momento. Para isso você deve estender a classe `Application`:

```
public class MeuAplicativo extends Application {

    private static MeuAplicativo mInstanciaDoAplicativo = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mInstanciaDoAplicativo = this;
    }

    public static MeuAplicativo getInstance() {
        if (mInstanciaDoAplicativo == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Este método não pode ser chamado antes da instância do aplicativo ter sido criada. Por exemplo, evite chamá-lo dentro de um método ou bloco estático.");
        }

        return mInstanciaDoAplicativo;
    }
}
```

A *exception* é muito difícil de acontecer. Em qualquer parte da sua implementação o contexto global já vai ter sido criado, exceto em blocos estáticos, que são um caso muito improvável de uso do contexto.

Não esqueça de informar a classe do aplicativo no `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:name="com.pacote.MeuAplicativo">
    ...
</application>
```

Feito isso, você pode acessar o contexto global em qualquer ponto do aplicativo assim:

```
MeuAplicativo.getInstance();
```